# Looking for a "lightbulb" that wirelessly controls an electrical outlet

Tags: electrical, smart-switch

To explain the context, I have a lightbulb socket in the ceiling of my apartment, which I do not want to use, and a floor lamp which I do want to use. The light in the ceiling is controlled by a light switch, but no outlets are controlled by any switch.

I'm not sure if such a product exists, but what I would like is something that I can plug into the lightbulb socket (or just wire up like a light fixture), and something that I can plug into my outlet, such that when I use the switch to turn on the light, the outlet is powered on, and when I turn off the light, the outlet is powered off.

Essentially I want a wireless connection between my ceiling light fixture and an electrical outlet on the wall.

I don't want to change the actual wiring in the apartment as:

- I'm renting it, I don't own it
- It's expensive
- I may want to move the lamp in the future

Does something like this exist? Ideally I'm looking for something that will work with European plugs/voltages, but products for other regions would still be helpful.

Comment: Would you be ok with activating the outlet with your phone? There are numerous products, both in-wall replacement receptacles and plug-in units, that allow control of outlets via smartphone and/or wireless hub/internet... some very inexpensive.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this? You plug the switched outlet into the regular outlet and the remote switch operates your new outlet. You can mount the switch where ever you want. These are available at many home stores and Walmarts. They're inexpensive, about $10 to 15 bucks

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Yes, I have seen these and have considered them. One of the reasons I'm less interested in this type of option is that the switch I have is actually paired with another on the far side of the room, and if possible I'm hoping to keep the ability to use both switches. If it was just a single switch I would be more inclined towards this type of solution

Comment: @GordonBailey you can get similar ones with two switches or buy two sets with the same frequency and use the two switches with the one plug.

Answer (score -1):

Depending if you want to play around with home automation solutions, it is trivially easy with a [Shelly relay](https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-1pm-smart-home-automation-relay/).

You wire the relay (which is wifi connected) behind the outlet, it is now switched on/off by by said relay. Behind the light switch you wire a [Shelly i3](https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-i3-smart-home-automation-device/) scene automator, powered by the mains (also on wifi), but now the switch is wired to the i3 instead of the light bulb.

Now the i3 can be programmed to switch on the other relays when the light switch is thrown, there is no external hardware, there is no separate automation hub required, power relays are CE marked, all APIs fully open, and you can also switch the outlets using a phone or a future automation system. All for about 40 euros.

I would suggest replacing the switch with a push button as it gives more control, as listed on the product page you can have double press and long press actions that differ, if you ever wanted to expand the ecosystem.

#### Edit 2020-10-01

As per comments, it should be noted that the relay is offered in non UL listed version, and a version UL certified for both the US and Canadian markets. Both are CE marked for European markets. The difference between the 2 versions is 5 euros, their European web shop selects the non UL version by default, and their US shop selects the UL version by default, but you are free to select either version if you choose. Their dual switching relay does not currently have a non UL listed version.

The actual difference between the UL and non UL version is the polymer shell and AC load/neutral connectors, which has higher temperature ratings for UL, but this is not listed on their product page.

Comment: Note that the OP cannot modify their wiring (due to being in a rental situation) and more importantly, CE is *worthless* in many parts of the world (vs. being listed/labeled by a third party laboratory such as UL, Intertek, TUV, CSA, ...)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel actually they do offer a UL version of that relay, and this does NOT modify the wiring, instead you are attaching the wiring to the relay instead of the outlet or switch, which is a 5 minute job with a screwdriver, and this meets all OPs requirements (in my opinion)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel also please dont think I am just shilling for the product, I answered this question because I am doing LITERALLY the exact same job at my house, and I am using these products to do it so it can operate independently of an automation system, but still tie in and report outlet and power usage status, or be overridden in case of emergency (fire alarm goes off, outlet with lamp turns on even if light switch is off)

Comment: Yeah -- I was able to figure out from your other answers that you weren't trying to pure-play shill, which is why I didn't drop a spam flag on this post.  You should probably mention the UL listed version of the relay in your post/link though...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I will now, and add another edit after I finish the job this weekend with how long it really took, including configuration